# Strange USB behaviour with PoE hat

Tags: usb, poe

This might be without PoE hat too but my device uses PoE hat.

Everything was working great, I have two USB ports used on the Pi:

- a USB hub with a keyboard and mouse
- and a 256GB Pen Drive

And that's been working great for about the last 4 days, until last night when I left it idle overnight.

Now the USB stick will not work, nor will the mouse and keyboard. The combinations that works and don't:

- Plugging everything into the USB hub, works
- Plugging the Pen Drive into the USB hub and everything else into the Pi USB sockets, works
- Plugging the Pen Drive into the Pi directly at all, doesn't work

The weirdest part? The hub is not powered, it relies entirely on the power provided by the Pi.

What could be going on here?

Comment: It might be related to this actually https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=220984&start=125#p1367460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only has this been fixed but you can also start buying the modified PoE hat as well, more information here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=220984&sid=41a3aeacbd67906bbe0ab14daed681c6&start=300#p1396911